# Trouble displaying results of sub query with php using salesforce SOAP api and partner wsdl

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

Here's a generic query sample that represents my problem.

```
$query = "SELECT Account.Name, Name from Contract WHERE AccountId = '001U0000003q6scIAA'";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);

foreach ($response->records as $record) {
$sObject = new SObject($response->records[0]);
var_dump($sObject);
echo $sObject->sobjects[0]->Name."<br/>\n";
echo $record->fields->Name."<br/>\n";
echo "*******************************<br/>\n";
echo "*******************************<br/>\n";
}
```

The problem is that the Account.Name field will not display. Just in case my entire method is wrong, The idea is to grab all of the contracts assigned to a specific account and display both the account name and the pertinent info from the contract. (so far all contract fields display perfectly. Just can't display the account name)

Thanks for the assistance in advance!

Here's the var_export().. (I removed all of my custom fields)

```
SObject::__set_state(array( 'type' => 'Contract', 'fields' => stdClass::__set_state(array(
'AccountId' => '001U0000003q6scIAA', 'Name' => 'test contract', '1' =>
SObject::__set_state(array( 'type' => 'Account', 'fields' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 
'Name' => 'test Account name', )), )), )), ))
```

Here's the var_dump() ...

```
object(SObject)#5 (2) { ["type"]=> string(8) "Contract" ["fields"]=> object(stdClass)#1871 (14) {
["AccountId"]=> string(18) "001U0000003q6scIAA" ["Name"]=> string(18) "Test Contract Name"
["1"]=> object(SObject)#1869 (2) { ["type"]=> string(7) "Account" ["fields"]=> object(stdClass)#1870 (1) { ["Name"]=> string(15) "Account Name" } } } }
```

Comment: You're using `$response->records` inside the `foreach` loop where you should probably just be using `$record`, right? :)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Without the $response->records I don't receive any info.  This is some of the output I get from the var_dump ..     object(SObject)#1869 (2) { ["type"]=> string(7) "Account" ["fields"]=> object(stdClass)#1870 (1) { ["Name"]=> string(15) "Account Name test" } }

Comment: I was just wondering why you're using both `echo $sObject->sobjects[0]->Name."<br/>\n";` and `echo $record->fields->Name."<br/>\n";`? :)

Comment: Just to test 2 ideas. both failed haha I'm pretty sure it's something simple in the php. var_export() confirms the proper data is there so the query is doing it's job. I just can't figure out how to display it for humans. I temporarily fixed it by running queries within the loop but that's a big no no and super slow.

Comment: `$sObject->fields->Name` should work, given that `var_dump` output. If not, can you edit the output of that `var_export`, along with the code that does work, into your original post?

Comment: $sObject->fields->Name works, but it's pulling the contract name. I need the result of the Account.Name lookup. I'll post the full var_export() in the original post..

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found something that put me on the right path. here's how I solved it...

```
foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    echo $record->fields->{1}->fields->Name."<br/>\n";
    echo $record->fields->Name."<br/>\n";
    echo "*******************************<br/>\n";
    echo "*******************************<br/>\n";
}
```

I had tried this approach originally but without the {} which gave an error. So all you have to do is look at the print_r() output, change the number to the number it gives you here - `["1"]=> object(SObject)#1869` and this query will show!

Thanks Daan for trying to help!